# Wisconsin Card Sorting task timing information

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, clinical-psychology

I've been trawling through the literature and the Wisconsin Card Sorting Task and I've yet to find any information regarding the timing of neuro-typical subjects vs. those who suffer from either brain damage or schizophrenia. Is this because the timing data across subject is irrelevant or nearly constant across subject? Alternatively, is this because the computerized version of the test has only recently been popularized?